Does Pydantic V2 compatible in AWS Lambda?
I had been trying to use Pydantic V2 in Lambda function. But no matter how many times I tried, how many methods. The error pydantic_core not found was still occured.
I followed both install dedicated pydantic_core from Pypi, but does not work.
I also try AWS Powertools approach, by installing aws-lambda-powertools and pydantic>=2.0.3 but still does not work.
I ended up use Pydantic V1 and aws-lambda-powertools[parser] and it works now.
So my question is that, is Pydantic V2 not compatible with AWS Lambda yet?

It would appear I get a version conflict when I run pip install  'aws-lambda-powertools[parser]>2' 'pydantic>2'. I also see pip trying to pull down each minor release of aws-lambda-powertools starting with latest and decreasing by one each time, looking for extra == "parser" until it hits 1.31.1. However if I don't specify [parser], it works fine with pip install  'aws-lambda-powertools>2' 'pydantic>2' and I can import just fine. So I think it's just the parser extra.
If I do install 'aws-lambda-powertools[all]', I get aws-lambda-powertools     2.37.0 and pydantic gets rolled back to pydantic-1.10.15. But after I do that, I can then do 'pip install 'pydantic>2'` and things once again work.
I'm not sure if there is a one-stop-shop way of installing both powertools with extras and pydantic2. That's exactly what I'm trying to figure out right now and I'll report back if I figure it out.
Edit: So we just ported our codebase to aws-lambda-powertools 2.37.0 and pydantic 2.7.1, but it took a little bit of fiddling. We had to stop using aws-lambda-powertools[all] extras and just define our transitive dependencies directly. Also it gives a lot of warnings because the ALP code is still using deprecated pydantic methods, but they are currently in the process of migrating that.
